# Read the unknown values returning from api

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I'm working with the github api and When i request for a particular query the result is like below

```
Object {result: Object, error: null}
     error: null
     result: Object

     __proto__: Object
```

and the result object structure is

```
result: Object
     CSS: 9927
     JavaScript: 44425 
     meta: Object
```

Meta object is common to all requests,

Each time the result is varies and and it returns four to five attributes too

Sometimes it may return only meta object

I have nothing to do with meta and I want to read the remaining variables.

How to do it using any libraries like jquery,underscore or javascript??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery:

If the result is in the variable `data`, you can use:

```
if (!data.error) {
    $.each(data.result, function(key, data) {
        if (key != 'meta') {
            console.log(key + ' = ' + data);
        }
    });
}
```